# How can I change the redirect that happens after a node is edited?

Tags: 7, redirection, nodes

Normally, after a node is edited, the user is sent to the node's display page.  I would like to change this so that the user is sent to a different page.  Is there a module for this or is there a native setting that I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

If you want to install a module and use a GUI you should be able to do that with [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules).  Just install the module, and setup a new rule to react on saving new content.

If you do not plan on using Rules for anything else, it is probably wiser to just use a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your custom module.  Just edit the forms `$form_state['redirect']` in a submit callback. Something like:

```
function test_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id=='MY_FORM') {
    array_push($form['#submit'], 'test_userlogin_submit');
  }
}

function test_userlogin_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'MY/NEW/PATH';
}
```

Comment: Great, that is something that you can do with rules.